# Java| XML type in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, xml, arraylist, types

### Could some one tell me how to make ArrayList with XML type.

example

```
ArrayList<XML> XMLs=new ArrayList<XML>();
```

but it tells me that java doesn't have any type like XML.

Comment: Yeah. There is not type called XML

Comment: but how to do something to solve this?

Comment: That is a huge answer.

Comment: by providing an existing class...

Comment: you may be misunderstanding what xml is

Comment: I think it is text file. So i think that I can have Datatype String or File for XML. But I might be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have an embedded class XML.

If you just need only a textual representation of your XML use simply `String`